# angularjs with oop inheritance in action

Tags: oop, angularjs

## Abstract

I'm working on an application that uses angular as a client side framework, angular currently rocks and I'm really happy using it, though now I find that I use to much copy and paste code that I would like to organize into class hierarchy. For example dialogs share a common set of functionality, they need to be opened, closed, the code that provides `typeahead` functionality is also a first candidate to inherit from some parent BaseTypeaheadClass, though  one thing I didn't find in angular is a standard way of organising these hierarchies. Both controllers, services, providers use ordinary javascript functions underneath which can be extended by the means of `prototype`, so my question is:

## Question

What is the angular way of organising my class functions, are there any standard mechanisms that will allow to derive one class from another

## P.S.

My guesses on the problem:

- Define implementation of base classes as services, as a result they will be easily injected into any controller or other services where that specific class will be needed
- Define `OOP` service and provide methods such as `define`, `derive`, etc. that will be used to create base / derived classes

---

## Edit

Some time has passed from time when I was initially asking my question. Since then I have come out with approach that I'm successfully using in several projects, that I like very much and want to share with everyone.

Currently angular doesn't provide any constructs for organising class hierarchies and it's a pity since more or less large application can't suffice only Model/View/Controller/... constructs, it has to organise it's code into OOP objects.

I'm working in the field of web-development for quite a long time already and I haven't seen even one enterprise project that was taking advantage of OOP with JavaScript massively. What I seen was huge and nicely organised server side / database side logic + close to infinite javascript spaghetti greased with zoo of frameworks and libraries on client side.

No MVVM, MVP frameworks such as knockout.js, backbone, other... are capable of replacing the OOP as such. If you are not using core principles of oriented programming such as Classes, Objects, Inheritance, Abstraction, Polymorphism you are in deep trouble, what you will end up is a mega long javascript spaghetti.

Regarding Angular I think it is a framework very much different from knockout.js / backbone.js / any other MVV-anything frameworks but according to my practice also it is not a silver bullet capable of replacing OOP. When I'm trying not to use the OOP with Angular I end up with duplicate logic located mostly in controllers. And unfortunately there is no (I have found no) clean and angular-way of beating that problem.

But I have successfully (I think) solved that problem.

I've used compact, zero-dependency lib that just implements `John Resig's Simple JavaScript Inheritance` (https://github.com/tracker1/core-js/blob/master/js-extensions/040-Class.js). With the help of that library I was able to create / inherit / create abstract methods / override them, in other words do everything that I've accustomed to on server side.

Here is an example usage:

```
Application.factory('SomeChildObject', ['$http', 'SomeParentClass', function ($http, SomeParentClass) {
    var SomeChildClass = SomeParentClass.extend({
        init: function() { // Constructor
            this._super.init(123, 231); // call base constructor
        },
        someFunction: function() {
            // Notice that your OOP now knows everything that can be injected into angular service, which is pretty cool :)
            $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).then(function(){
                this._super.someFunction(); // call base function implementation
            });
        }
    });

    // return new SomeChildClass(); // We are not returning instance here!

    return SomeChildClass; // Service is a function definition not an instance of an object
}]);

// So now we can both use this service in angular and have the ability to extend it using the `extend` method call, like so:
Application.controller('MegaController', ['$scope', 'SomeChildClass', function ($scope, SomeChildClass) {
    $scope.someObject = new SomeChildClass();
}]);
```

OOP + Angular play together very nicely, objects created under angular context can take advantage of dependency injection via services automatically, so you don't have to inject instances into your OOP constructors and this fact makes your OOP hierarchy very slim and free of irrelevant stuff that needs to be (and is) handled by angular.js

So play with this approach and give feedback here with results you gained or problems you encountered,

## Another edit

Recently I've faced few problems with original Class.js implementation, as follows:

1) If you will be passing a reference to your instance methods as callbacks to other methods, these methods might work not the way you expect them to work. They will loose reference to `this`. In such case you will be expecting to see your current object inside `this` but it will be either top level `Window` or some other context object depending on how the callback calls your method. It happens due to JavaScript architecture. In order to fight this problem a special `ClassMember` function is provided which instructs `Class` to bind your method to object context when it is being created (check `Usage` below for further guidance).

2) Obviously original `Class.js` implementation doesn't know anything about angular type of controller method declarations i.e.

```
Class.extend('YourClassDisplayName', {
    ctor: function () {
        // Some useful constructor logic
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
        // Do something with $scope and $attrs
    }]
});
```

Current implementation understands above syntax

3) When using above approach without appropriate handling it would break angular `$$annotate`'on process so referring to above example it would make impossible to inject `$scope` and `$attrs` into into `ClassMember` method, or overridden method which is using `this.base(...)` calls. So this is also fixed.

**Gotchas:**

1) When using `this.base(...)` within async operation handler (something like `$http.get(..., function() { self.base(...); })`) please note that `this.base(...)` call has a limited lifetime and as soon as the method returns `this.base(...)` stops existing. So you should save reference to base method explicitly if you are planning to call base methods in asynchronous fashion. i.e:

```
...
var self = this;
var base = this.base;
...
$http.get(..., function () {
    base.call(self, ...); // or base.apply(self, ...), or base() if you don't care about `this`
})
```

I've resolved all of the above problems (except one gotcha which can not be resolved due to JavaScript architecture) and would like to share with everyone, hope you will benefit from it:

```
/* Simple JavaScript Inheritance
 * By John Resig http://ejohn.org/
 * MIT Licensed.
 *
 * Inspired by base2 and Prototype

 * Angular adaptations by Denis Yaremov http://github.com/lu4
 * Usage:
 ---------------------------------

   var X = Class.extend('X', {
       ctor: function () {
           this.name = "I'm X";
       },

       myOrdinaryMethod: function (x, y, z) {
           console.log([this.name, x, y, z]);
       },

       myClassMemberMethod: ClassMember(function (x, y, z) {
           console.log([this.name, x, y, z]);
       })
   });

   var Y = Class.extend('Y', {
       ctor: function () {
           this.name = "I'm Y";
       },

       myOrdinaryMethod: function (x, y, z) {
           console.log([this.name, x, y, z]);
       },

       myClassMemberMethod: ClassMember(function (x, y, z) {
           console.log([this.name, x, y, z]);
       })
   });

   var x = new X();
   var y = new Y();

   x.myClassMemberMethod('a', 'b', 'c'); // ["I'm X", "a", "b", "c"] 
   y.myClassMemberMethod('u', 'v', 'm'); // ["I'm Y", "u", "v", "m"] 

   x.myOrdinaryMethod('a', 'b', 'c'); // ["I'm X", "a", "b", "c"] 
   y.myOrdinaryMethod('u', 'v', 'm'); // ["I'm Y", "u", "v", "m"] 

   y.theirOrdinaryMethod = x.myOrdinaryMethod;
   y.theirClassMemberMethod = x.myClassMemberMethod;

   y.theirOrdinaryMethod('a', 'b', 'c'); // ["I'm Y", "a", "b", "c"] 
   y.theirClassMemberMethod('u', 'v', 'm'); // ["I'm X", "u", "v", "m"]

*/

angular.module('app').factory('ClassMember', function () {
    return function ClassMember(fn) {
        if (this instanceof ClassMember) {
            this.fn = fn;
        } else {
            return new ClassMember(fn);
        }
    };
});

angular.module('app').factory('Class', function (ClassMember) {
    var runtime = { initializing: false },
        fnTest = /xyz/.test(function() { xyz; }) ? /\bbase\b/ : /.*/,
        FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m,
        STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;

    var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

    // The base Class implementation (does nothing)
    function Class() { };

    Class.members = { };

    // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
    Class.extend = function extend(displayName, properties) {
        var array;

        var targetMembers = {};
        var sourceMembers = this.members;

        for (var memberName in sourceMembers) {
            if (sourceMembers.hasOwnProperty(memberName)) {
                targetMembers[memberName] = sourceMembers[memberName];
            }
        }

        var base = this.prototype;

        // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
        // don't run the ctor constructor)
        runtime.initializing = true;
        var prototype = new this();
        runtime.initializing = false;

        // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
        for (var name in properties) {
            if (properties.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
                var property = properties[name];

                // Support angular's controller/service/factory declaration notation
                if (toString.call(property) === '[object Array]') {
                    array = property;

                    var item = array[array.length - 1];

                    if (toString.call(item) === '[object Function]' || item instanceof ClassMember) {
                        property = array[array.length - 1];
                    } else {
                        array = null;
                    }
                } else {
                    array = null;
                }

                var isClassMember = property instanceof ClassMember;

                if (isClassMember) {
                    property = property.fn;
                }

                if (typeof property === "function") {
                    if (typeof base[name] === "function" && fnTest.test(property)) {
                        property = (function (propertyName, fn) {
                            var args = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '').match(FN_ARGS)[1];
                            return (new Function('propertyName', 'fn', 'base', 'return function (' + args + ') {\n\
                                    var prevBase = this.base;\n\
                                    var hasBase = "base" in this;\n\
\n\
                                    // Add a new .base() method that is the same method\n\
                                    // but on the super-class\n\
\n\
                                    this.base = base[propertyName];\n\
\n\
                                    // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we\n\
                                    // remove it when we\'re done executing\n\
                                    var ret = fn.call(this' + (!!args ? (', ' + args) : args) + ');\n\
\n\
                                    if (hasBase) {\n\
                                        this.base = prevBase;\n\
                                    } else {\n\
                                        delete this["base"];\n\
                                    }\n\
                                    return ret;\n\
                                }'))(propertyName, fn, base);
                        })(name, property);
                    }

                    if (isClassMember) {
                        targetMembers[name] = property;
                    } else if (name in targetMembers) {
                        delete targetMembers[name];
                    }

                    if (array) {
                        array[array.length - 1] = property;

                        property = array;
                    }

                    prototype[name] = property;
                } else {
                    prototype[name] = property;
                }
            }
        }

        var membersArray = [];
        for (var i in targetMembers) {
            if (targetMembers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                membersArray.push({ name: i, fn: targetMembers[i] });
            }
        }

        // All construction is actually done in the ctor method
        var ChildClass = (new Function("runtime", "members", "FN_ARGS", "STRIP_COMMENTS", "return function " + (displayName || "Class") + "() {\n\
            if (!runtime.initializing && this.ctor)\n\
            {\n\
                var length = members.length;\n\
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)\n\
                {\n\
                    var item = members[i];\n\
                    this[item.name] = (function (me, fn) {\n\
                        var args = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '').match(FN_ARGS)[1];\n\
                        return args ? (new Function('me', 'fn', 'return function (' + args + ') { return fn.call(me, ' + args + '); }'))(me, fn) : function () { return fn.call(me); };\n\
                    })(this, item.fn);\n\
\n\
                }\n\
                this.ctor.apply(this, arguments);\n\
            }\n\
        }"))(runtime, membersArray, FN_ARGS, STRIP_COMMENTS);

        ChildClass.members = targetMembers;

        // Populate our constructed prototype object
        ChildClass.prototype = prototype;

        // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
        ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;

        // And make this class extendable
        ChildClass.extend = extend;

        return ChildClass;
    };

    return Class;
});
```

---

## Another edit

Eventually I've stumbled upon another problem related to original John Resig's implementation in relation to angular, and the problem is related to angular's annotation process (used for dependency injection) which uses Function.prototype.toString() and some Regex'es for the purpose of extracting the names of dependencies. And the problem with original implementation is that it doesn't expect this and so you are not able to declare methods that accept dependencies, so I've tweaked the implementation a little bit to deal with previously described problem and here it is:

```
/* Simple JavaScript Inheritance
 * By John Resig http://ejohn.org/
 * MIT Licensed.
 *
 * Inspired by base2 and Prototype

 * Angular adaptations by Denis Yaremov http://github.com/lu4
 * Usage:
 ---------------------------------

   var X = Class.extend('X', {
       ctor: function () {
           this.name = "I'm X";
       },

       myOrdinaryMethod: function (x, y, z) {
           console.log([this.name, x, y, z]);
       },

       myClassMemberMethod: ClassMember(function (x, y, z) {
           console.log([this.name, x, y, z]);
       })
   });

   var Y = Class.extend('Y', {
       ctor: function () {
           this.name = "I'm Y";
       },

       myOrdinaryMethod: function (x, y, z) {
           console.log([this.name, x, y, z]);
       },

       myClassMemberMethod: ClassMember(function (x, y, z) {
           console.log([this.name, x, y, z]);
       })
   });

   var x = new X();
   var y = new Y();

   x.myClassMemberMethod('a', 'b', 'c'); // ["I'm X", "a", "b", "c"] 
   y.myClassMemberMethod('u', 'v', 'm'); // ["I'm Y", "u", "v", "m"] 

   x.myOrdinaryMethod('a', 'b', 'c'); // ["I'm X", "a", "b", "c"] 
   y.myOrdinaryMethod('u', 'v', 'm'); // ["I'm Y", "u", "v", "m"] 

   y.theirOrdinaryMethod = x.myOrdinaryMethod;
   y.theirClassMemberMethod = x.myClassMemberMethod;

   y.theirOrdinaryMethod('a', 'b', 'c'); // ["I'm Y", "a", "b", "c"] 
   y.theirClassMemberMethod('u', 'v', 'm'); // ["I'm X", "u", "v", "m"]

*/


angular.module('homer').factory('Class', function () {
    function ClassMember(fn) {
        if (this instanceof ClassMember) {
            this.fn = fn;
            return this;
        } else {
            return new ClassMember(fn);
        }
    }

    function ClassEvent() {
        if (this instanceof ClassEvent) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return new ClassEvent();
        }
    }

    var runtime = { initializing: false },
        fnTest = /xyz/.test(function () { xyz; }) ? /\bbase\b/ : /.*/,
        fnArgs = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m,
        stripComments = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;

    var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

    // The base Class implementation (does nothing)
    function Class() { };

    Class.events = {};
    Class.members = {};

    // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
    Class.extend = function Extend(displayName, properties) {
        var array;

        var targetEvents = {};
        var sourceEvents = this.events;

        var targetMembers = {};
        var sourceMembers = this.members;

        for (var eventName in sourceEvents) {
            if (sourceEvents.hasOwnProperty(eventName)) {
                targetEvents[eventName] = sourceEvents[eventName];
            }
        }

        for (var memberName in sourceMembers) {
            if (sourceMembers.hasOwnProperty(memberName)) {
                targetMembers[memberName] = sourceMembers[memberName];
            }
        }

        var base = this.prototype;

        // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
        // don't run the ctor constructor)
        runtime.initializing = true;
        var prototype = new this();
        runtime.initializing = false;

        // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
        for (var name in properties) {
            if (properties.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
                var property = properties[name];

                // Support angular's controller/service/factory declaration notation
                if (toString.call(property) === '[object Array]') {
                    array = property;

                    var item = array[array.length - 1];

                    if (toString.call(item) === '[object Function]' || item instanceof ClassMember) {
                        property = array[array.length - 1];
                    } else {
                        array = null;
                    }
                } else {
                    array = null;
                }

                var isClassMember = property instanceof ClassMember;

                if (isClassMember) {
                    property = property.fn;
                }

                var isClassEvent = property instanceof ClassEvent;

                if (isClassEvent) {
                    property = (function() {
                        function Subscriber(fn) {
                            Subscriber.listeners.push(fn.bind(this));
                        };

                        Subscriber.listeners = [];
                        Subscriber.fire = function() {
                            var listeners = Subscriber.listeners;

                            for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
                                var result = listeners[i].apply(this, arguments);

                                if (result !== undefined) return result;
                            }

                            return void 0;
                        }

                        return Subscriber;
                    })();
                }

                if (typeof property === "function") {
                    if (typeof base[name] === "function" && fnTest.test(property)) {
                        property = (function (propertyName, fn) {
                            var args = fn.toString().replace(stripComments, '').match(fnArgs)[1];
                            return (new Function('propertyName', 'fn', 'base', 'return function (' + args + ') {\n\
                                    var prevBase = this.base;\n\
                                    var hasBase = "base" in this;\n\
\n\
                                    // Add a new .base() method that is the same method\n\
                                    // but on the super-class\n\
\n\
                                    this.base = base[propertyName];\n\
\n\
                                    // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we\n\
                                    // remove it when we\'re done executing\n\
                                    var ret = fn.call(this' + (!!args ? (', ' + args) : args) + ');\n\
\n\
                                    if (hasBase) {\n\
                                        this.base = prevBase;\n\
                                    } else {\n\
                                        delete this["base"];\n\
                                    }\n\
                                    return ret;\n\
                                }'))(propertyName, fn, base);
                        })(name, property);
                    }

                    if (isClassEvent) {
                        targetEvents[name] = property;
                    } else {
                        delete targetEvents[name];
                    }

                    if (isClassMember) {
                        targetMembers[name] = property;
                    } else if (name in targetMembers) {
                        delete targetMembers[name];
                    }

                    if (array) {
                        array[array.length - 1] = property;

                        property = array;
                    }

                    prototype[name] = property;
                } else {
                    prototype[name] = property;
                }
            }
        }

        var eventsArray = [];
        for (var targetEventName in targetEvents) {
            if (targetEvents.hasOwnProperty(targetEventName)) {
                eventsArray.push({ name: targetEventName, fn: targetEvents[targetEventName] });
            }
        }

        var membersArray = [];
        for (var targetMemberName in targetMembers) {
            if (targetMembers.hasOwnProperty(targetMemberName)) {
                membersArray.push({ name: targetMemberName, fn: targetMembers[targetMemberName] });
            }
        }

        // All construction is actually done in the ctor method
        var ChildClass = (new Function("runtime", "events", "members", "FN_ARGS", "STRIP_COMMENTS", "return function " + (displayName || "Class") + "() {\n\
            if (!runtime.initializing && this.ctor)\n\
            {\n\
                var length = members.length;\n\
                var bind = function (me, $$fn$$) {\n\
                    var args = $$fn$$.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '').match(FN_ARGS)[1];\n\
                    var result = args ? (new Function('me', '$$fn$$', 'return function (' + args + ') { return $$fn$$.apply(me, arguments); }'))(me, $$fn$$) : function () { return $$fn$$.apply(me, arguments); };\n\
                    return result;\n\
                };\n\
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)\n\
                {\n\
                    var item = members[i];\n\
                    var fn = item.fn;\n\
                    var name = item.name;\n\
                    var property = this[name] = bind(this, fn);\n\
                    if (fn.fire) {\n\
                        property.fire = bind(this, fn.fire);\n\
                    }\n\
                    if (fn.listeners) {\n\
                        property.listeners = fn.listeners;\n\
                    }\n\
                }\n\
                \n\
                var length = events.length;\n\
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)\n\
                {\n\
                    var item = events[i];\n\
                    var fn = item.fn;\n\
                    var name = item.name;\n\
                    var property = this[name] = bind(this, fn);\n\
                    if (fn.fire) {\n\
                        property.fire = bind(this, fn.fire);\n\
                    }\n\
                    if (fn.listeners) {\n\
                        property.listeners = fn.listeners;\n\
                    }\n\
                }\n\
                this.ctor.apply(this, arguments);\n\
            }\n\
        }"))(runtime, eventsArray, membersArray, fnArgs, stripComments);

        ChildClass.members = targetMembers;

        // Populate our constructed prototype object
        ChildClass.prototype = prototype;

        // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
        ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;

        // And make this class extendable
        ChildClass.extend = Extend;
        ChildClass.event = ClassEvent;
        ChildClass.member = ClassMember;

        return ChildClass;
    };

    Class.member = ClassMember;
    Class.event = ClassEvent;

    return Class;
});
```

Comment: Hi, do you still use the John Resig inheritance in way you described in your example? Do you face the problem with "deep inheritance"? I tried to make the same thing, but if my `BaseClass` has an object inside, then this approach not works, because all instances of Child Classes have reference to the same instance of "object property". So I don't know if it's a conceptual problem or I'm just using the bad version of John Resig class implementation. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Alex, no I wasn't using deep inheritance approach, however I've faced other problem related to circular dependency (consider the following reading -> http://goo.gl/g5OBNC + http://goo.gl/FUBFwF). As a result I've came up to a thought that the circular dependency problem is a result of bad coding habits which may struck me whenever  I'm not waiting for that. So regarding your problem, I think that nesting classes is kinda bad thing to do since you will not be able to  test them in isolation due to prototypical nature of javascript. Have you tried reconsidering your architecture?

Comment: Btw. There are ton of more sophisticated inheritance frameworks out there in internet, so you may also try to substitute the exact John Resig's inheritance with someone other's inheritance, but again, I would not recommend nesting classes into themselves in general, in such way you are violating dependency boundaries, by making one dependency contain two classes (this is btw the solution I came to, before I have read about circular deps)...

Comment: You should add a plunker with a demo - this sounds fascinating

Comment: Stackoverflow ticket on the same subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483555/angular-js-best-practice-extending-controllers-overriding-controller-defaults

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your guesses sounds perfectly applicable.

You can reuse functionality defined in parent controllers by simply calling methods attached to the parent scope:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <!-- Something here ... -->
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
        <!-- Something here ... -->
    </div>
    <!-- Something here ... -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.parentMethod = function () {
        //method body
    };
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.childMethod = function () {
        //functionality
        $scope.parentMethod();
        //functionality
    };
}
```

If you want to use the JavaScript approach with prototype inheritance you can use:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function Parent($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';    

    $scope.clickParent = function() {
        $scope.name = 'Clicked from base controller';
    }    
}

function Child($scope, $injector) {

    debugger;
    $injector.invoke(Parent, this, {$scope: $scope});

    $scope.name = 'Superhero Child';

    $scope.clickChild = function(){
        $scope.clickParent();
    }       
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mhevery/u6s88/12/

For services, for example, you can use:

```
(function () {

function ParentService(arg1) {
   this.arg1 = arg1;
}

function ChildService(arg1, arg2) {
   ParentService.call(this, arg1);
   this.arg2 = arg2;
}

ChildService.prototype = new ParentService();

app.service('ChildService', ChildService);

}());
```

Also check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular/controller$20inheritance/angular/qqncwxdcVgw/Kqoswky69-oJ) discussion and the [blog post about inheritance in AngularJS](http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/) I posted.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful answer and so are examples, but I would probably use app.factory instead of app.service, this will allow to define a class function within service's function scope, so that we don't mess up the global scope and keep it's definition private for global vars from one side and absolutely public to angular infrastructure

Comment: One tip: instead of call use apply ParentService.apply(this, arguments); this way if you add new arguments to the base class you are not in danger of forgetting to add them to the call

Comment: @Lu4 you can use IIFE to preserve the global namespace (I've used it in my last example).

Comment: how do you test this? I have trouble getting the base class in as a dependency.

Comment: Remove the IIFE and expose the constructor functions in the global scope.

Comment: Hm. I think our 'use strict' linter is going to barf on that.

Comment: It won't. You don't need to put your code inside IIFE if it is not in production. You can use gulp/grunt in order to wrap everything inside IIFE automatically.
Using globals for testing is fine.

Comment: I removed IIFE from tests, base and subclass (in my case controllers).  I still get 'undefined' is not an object at 'app.BaseController.extend' where BaseController is defined as a controller right on our global app object. Perhaps I should break this out into a question.

Comment: Yes, I guess it'll be better to do so.

Comment: Here's a link to the question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045956/how-to-test-an-angular-app-with-class-inheritance

Answer (score 6):

Let me give you my opinion on Angular / inheritance situation.

> You don't do class/prototypical inheritance in Angular.js. It can be hard to test, and that is a problem. For those, who are looking for 'inheritance' in Angular, I recommend this:
>
> **Your base class is the controller**. The controller is an abstract model anyways, so it is perfect for that purpose. Use a $scope.init() function in your controller, but don't call it from there!
>
> **If you want to 'extend' your controller's functionality, use directives**. In you directive link() function, call the controller's $scope.init(). (when compiling, angular runs controllers first, and directive link functions after). If scope had a `$scope.name='base'`, in the directive link you will be able to redefine `$scope.name=child`, and after that, run $scope.init().
>
> But wait! But this only allows a single-level inheritance. - Yes, thats true. But if you are looking for multilevel inheritance, you should use *Services*.
>
> **Multilevel inheritance is nothing else, but sharing the same code in a hierarchical class structure. For this purpose, use Services**, and throw in these services with the dependency injector into your directives. Soo easy. This should be easy to accomplish, easy to understand, and tests run smooth.

Directives are very powerful tools, because you can dynamically combine partials with controllers.

Comment: Man I've read your post approx. 10 times, frankly speaking, I have a negative perception of what you are trying to say (the one that is close to raging anger and massively heavy cognitive dissonance). The paradigm that can be found behind inheritance (I'm talking about OOP) is a tool that is used for solving certain tasks. Just like hammer, it was invented centuries ago and there is no tool that can ever replace it without eventually being called a 'hammer', look like hammer, sound like hammer and be like hammer.

Comment: The other (more problematic) aspect (in my opinion) of your proposition is the fact that instead of using a hammer you propose using a christmas tree that is sticked into butt of a chicken coiled down to a microscope with adhesive tape and a barrel of a superglue http://goo.gl/NXWbJa.

Man, you don't say "You don't do class/prototypical inheritance in Angular.js" cuz you don't provide at least minimal example that would explain what you mean... (This is joke)

Comment: I have had some success doing as you suggest, using controllers as the abstract definition, templates as the child class definitions.

Answer (score 3):

I think your guesses are pretty good and I played with a few approaches like that, but they all turned out more verbose than I had hoped.

I had a problem where I had developed a complex dialog as a tab in our admin interface, but I wanted an almost identical dialog in a popup in the user section, but the data would be populated from a different source and there would be a few additional buttons. Basically a great candidate for classical inheritance. For the UI side I used a template which was included in two places with different controllers. But to avoid duplicating the complex UI logic in the controllers I wanted to use inheritance.

The scope inheritance method relies somewhat on the structure of the application and wasn't appropriate because the two UIs were in effectively different applications. The approach of putting reused code into services would end up being verbose as I would have needed to have each controller method call an equivalent method on the service. So I used the following simple approach to JavaScript inheritance:

```
/**
 * Effective base class for Thing Controllers.
 * This should be considered abstract since it does not define
 * $scope.readData() or $scope.saveData() which may be called from its
 * other functions.
 */
function BaseThingController($scope, $http){
    $scope.data = []; // local data store;
    $scope.validateForm(){...}
    $scope.edit(){...}
    $scope.cancel(){...}
    $scope.reset(){...}
    $scope.otherMethod1(){...}
    $scope.otherMethod2(){...}
    $scope.otherMethod3(){...}
}

/**
 * AdminThingController effectively extends BaseThingController
 */
function AdminThingController($scope, $http){
    // Calling BaseThingController as a function defines all the needed 
    // functions and properties in our scope.
    BaseThingController($scope, $http)

    $scope.readData(){
       // $scope.data = data from admin data source
    }

    $scope.saveData(newData){
       // save to special admin service
    }

    // initialize local data
    $scope.readData()
}

/**
 * UserThingController effectively extends BaseThingController
 */
function UserThingController($scope, $http){
    // Calling BaseThingController as a function defines all the needed 
    // functions and properties in our scope.
    BaseThingController($scope, $http)

    $scope.readData(){
       // $scope.data = data from user data source
    }

    $scope.saveData(newData){
       // save to user service
    }

   /**
    * Overriding base class behaviour here
    */
   $scope.otherMethod1(){...}

    // initialize local data
    $scope.readData()

}
```

So I've not used prototype inheritance as the $scope is readily available. But I have gained all the behaviour from the base controller and only added or overridden what I want to. My views could be configured with either controller and would work with no modifications.

Comment: I've tried this approach back at time when I was writing this post, it has it's own pros and cons, though what I've end up using was `John Resig's Simple JavaScript Inheritance` aproach because I thought that scope must be clean of stuff that is not scope specific, i.e. you can't compose two different objects on one scope. This approach is nicely implemented in core-js (https://github.com/tracker1/core-js/blob/master/js-extensions/040-Class.js). Basically I've used Angular services as a point of distribution for classes implemented with `core-js` `Class.extend(...)` definition

Comment: I see your point about keeping the scope clean, and your approach is very concise, but if I put your example in front of a junior developer and asked them to add a new feature I think they would spend half an hour trying to understand the code and looking up what js-core is. I might be in the same boat if I came back in 5 years to review the code. My approach is more primitive but obvious to developers and reviewers alike. I guess it is largely a matter of taste and environment.