# How to get service instance from module instance [Angular]

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular-services

i have some module defined and services too with that module like below

```
var services=angular.module('app.services', []);
services.factory('ApiService', function($http,$cookies,UserService){

        var dataFactory = {};

        dataFactory.request=function(url,data,next){
            return "Hi";
        };

        return dataFactory;

});
```

now in another script i can access module like

```
services=angular.module('app.services')
```

but how can i get service instance from that module like

```
apiService=angular.module('app.services').service('ApiService')
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the instance? They are meant to be injected into controllers.

Comment: i want to access outside on app.init (my another fucntion) function (which i've created for starting app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit:

after reading and understanding the author's comments, he was actually meant to block the entire app if the user is not permitted. his desired to do it by reusing the same code written in his `ApiService` factory.

--

You can 'hook' to  [app.run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20664122/3191896) function which called before your controllers and you can utilize `$window.location.href` to relocate user to another page or site (if not permitted)

Iv'e updated this **<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYzybxhiFSVQpr9aZtfl?p=preview)</kbd>** with `app.run` entry

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.services']);

app.run(function(ApiService, $window) {
  result = ApiService.request();

  // This is where you check your permissions
  var has_permissions = false;
  // ...

  if (!has_permissions) {
    alert('being transferred to plnkr.co due to lack of permissions');
    $window.location.href = 'http://plnkr.co/';
  }

  // Otherwise, continue normally

});
```

---

### Original:

i made this **<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYzybxhiFSVQpr9aZtfl?p=preview)</kbd>**

if you separate all logic to `api.services` module, include it in your app

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.services']);
```

then you could use it by referencing the desired factory - `ApiService`

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'ApiService',
  function($scope, ApiService) {

    $scope.result = ApiService.request();

  }
]);
```

**app.services.js**

```
var services = angular.module('app.services', []);


services.factory('UserService', function() {

  var UserService = {};

  UserService.foo = function() {
    return "foo";
  };

  return UserService;

});


services.factory('ApiService', function($http, UserService) {

  var ApiService = {};

  ApiService.request = function(url, data, next) {
    return UserService.foo() + " Hi";
  };

  return ApiService;

});
```

---

**<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYzybxhiFSVQpr9aZtfl?p=preview)</kbd>**

[image]

Comment: You want to get the service before or after the app initialization?

Comment: module.run() did that job for me from above answer but that way i can't block app to run..

Comment: when app is bootstrapping can we have something like beforeRun() so i can check something and approve app to run

Comment: If you would like to decide whether to run the app or not, you could remove the `ng-app` and do the bootstrapping manually when desired.

Comment: i am doing so.. but that time i also need to call service to check weather it should run or not...i can start app but don't want to fire routing at least... thanks for all you doing.

Comment: Is the `call service to check weather it should run or not` asynchronous? I mean it is an ajax request?

Comment: ok. it's more clear now. 
there is `app.run` entry point where you could utilize for your needs

http://nadeemkhedr.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/how-to-do-authorization-and-role-based-permissions-in-angularjs/

Comment: thanks buddy i got your point but for this i'll write my code in main app class, instead of isolating within service.

Comment: means i can't write $.get('/api/UserPermission', function(data) { in app.js

Comment: But this doesn't block the app from running. If you are ok with that, I'm confused of what you are trying to acheive in the first place.

Comment: @runTarm, you are right. one way to block the app it's by url redirect. something like `$location.url('...');`. i will update the answer

Comment: yes i'll try that too and now moved my ajax code in app.js just got inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344214/problems-with-circular-dependency-and-oop-in-angularjs