# Why injecting `$http` in angular 1 error interceptor cause circular dependency?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

Consider the following interceptor template for angular 1

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('myApp')
            .factory('apiError', apiError);

        apiError.$inject = [
            '$q',
            '$injector',
            '$http'];

        function apiError($q,
                          $injector,
                          $http) {

        }
    })();
```

Injecting `$q` and `$injector` will not encounter any problem, but injecting `$http` will cause circular dependency error.

```
Error: $injector:cdep
Circular Dependency
```

The fix I made is simply setting `$http` using `$injector` inline

```
 var $http = $injector.get('$http');
```

But I have two questions

1. Why is there circular dependency?
2. How did `$injector` solved the circular dependency

Comment: start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344214/problems-with-circular-dependency-and-oop-in-angularjs