# Messaging between two angularjs services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, angular-services, postmessage

I want to realise a communication (by sending and receiving messages) between two services in an angularjs web site. Actually, messaging would be unnecessary if we could merge two services into one service. But the reality is I don't want to merge them for some reason. As **mutual dependency of two services is not possible** (please correct me if i am wrong), it seems that I have to let them communicate via messaging.

Let me explain... Assume we have two services `serA` and `serB`. In `serA`, we have

```
this.startTask1 = function () {
    console.log("B, please do task 1")
    sendMsgFromAtoB("B, please do task 1")
}

this.receiveMsgFromBtoA = function (msg) {
    if (msg === "A, B has done task 1") {
        console.log("A, B has done task 1"); 
        console.log("task 1 is finally over!!!")
    }
}
```

in `serB`, we have

```
this.receiveMsgFromAtoB = function (msg) {
    if (msg === "B, please do task 1") {
        console.log("B is doing task 1... Done!");
        sendMsgFromBtoA("A, B has done task 1")
    }
}
```

As a result, if a controller runs `serA.startTask1()`, I expect to see in the console:

```
B, please do task 1
B is doing task 1... Done!
A, B has done task 1
task 1 is finally over!!!
```

To this end, I need to make `sendMsgFromAtoB` and `sendMsgFromBtoA`, and complete `receiveMsgFromAtoB` and `receiveMsgFromBtoA`. However, I don't know by which mean I could implement them.

I have used `$window.addEventListener("message", ...)` (ie, `postMessage`) and `$window.addEventListener("storage", ...)` (ie, `StorageEvent`). But `StorageEvent` is not fully cross-platform, I am not sure `postMessage` is good for messaging inside 1 page.

So does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: If the task in service B is asynchronous, return a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). If the task is synchronous, simply use a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got event bus in Angular 1.x app, `$rootScope`. Unless you're willing to introduce third-party libraries to the project (RxJS, EventEmitter3 or other pub/sub implementations), there's no reason to look any further.

```
$rootScope.$on('foo', (e, arg1, arg2) => { ... });
...
$rootScope.$emit('foo', arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 1):

A circular dependency is always the sign of [mixing of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), which is a really bad thing. Miško Hevery, one of the authors of AngularJS, explains a nice solution on [his awesome blog](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/). In short, you probably have a third service hidden somewhere, which is the only part of your code really needed by the two others.

Change:

```
+---------+      +---------+
|    A    |<-----|  B      |
|         |      |  |  +-+ |
|         |      |  +->|C| |
|         |------+---->| | |
|         |      |     +-+ |
+---------+      +---------+
```

To this:

```
                         +---------+
+---------+              |    B    |
|    A    |<-------------|         |
|         |              |         |
|         |    +---+     |         |
|         |--->| C |<----|         |
|         |    +---+     +---------+
+---------+
```

See also,

- [Problems with circular dependency and OOP in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344214/problems-with-circular-dependency-and-oop-in-angularjs)
- [*Miško Hevery*, Circular Dependency in constructors and Dependency Injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/)