# How to test an angular app with class inheritance?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, inheritance, testing, karma-runner

I can test normal controllers fine. I cannot test controllers that inherit a base controller.

This is how we've been defining subclassed-controllers:

```
 app.NavController = app.BaseController.extend({
    ...
 });
```

This is the base:

```
app.BaseController = Class.extend({
    $scope: null,

    init: function($scope) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.defineListeners();
        this.defineScope();
    },

    defineListeners: function() {
        // this.$scope.$on('$destroy',this.destroy.bind(this));
    },
    ...
});

app.controller('BaseController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    return new app.BaseController($scope);
}]);
```

However, running Karma produces:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'app.BaseController.extend')
```

Is there a different way of doing this? I've removed IIFE wrappers for testing. Class.js is included in my Karmaconfig. I'm using John Resig's Class inheritance.

Comment: My teammate may have defined BaseController on app because he was doing IIFE wrappers. Maybe that is not necessary? We can define BaseController just as a global?

Comment: Can you provide some of your testing code?

Comment: This failed due to just including it on the page in Karma. I believe this happened before the specs ran. We actually came up with a solution using $controller and overwriting prototype.

Answer (score 1):

by adding this to instantiate the sub-classes prototype, we can get access to base class by simply injecting $controller as a dependency.

```
app.controller('SubController', ['$scope','$location','$controller',
        function($scope, $location, $controller) {
            var controller = {

...
controller.prototype = $controller('BaseController', {
                $scope: $scope
            });
            controller.init($location);
return controller;
```